# How can I search multiple files for a pattern in parallel and stop after the first search

Tags: grep, find, xargs, head

I was using `find folder/*/*/specific_folder -name "file*' -print 0 | xargs -0 -P 8 fgrep -m 1 --no -filename - A 1000 numberpattern | head -n 1`

I want to parallely search for a string across multiple files and stop after the first match.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel --halt now,success=1 grep -m 1 PATTERN ::: file*
```

Or, the other way around:

```
find ... -print0 | parallel -0 --halt now,success=1 grep -m 1 PATTERN
```

Comment: I tried the second option like so:
find /aaa/bbb/ccc/*/*/ddd -name "file*" -print0 | parallel -0 --halt 
now,success=1 grep -m 1 1234 

I got the following error: 
Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at /path/path/Path.pm line 123

Comment: I don't believe `find` accepts wildcards like that. Please try the `find` alone.

Comment: Ive used that find command before and its worked perfectly fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just tested it on my macOS machine and it works fine. What OS are you using? Do you have filenames with newlines in them? Have you tried putting your PATTERN in double quotes?

Comment: If your files are located in `folder/.../.../something` you can see if any contain a newline with `find folder | grep -v "^folder"` because that shows you lines that don't start with `folder`.